# How to redirect a url to home page if the input value has "!"?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

If any user submit the `!` character as input value I want to redirect the URL to the home page.

```
 example.com/index.php?c%5B%5D=%21&c%5B%5D=&c%5B%5D=&c%5B%5D=&c%5B%5D=&ic=&submit=find
```

If multiple input values are submitted with the character `!` I want to be redirected to the main page else the code works on the same page.

For example, in this URL:

```
https://www.example.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=!&From=USD&To=EUR
```

the value `!` is contained so I want to redirect it to my page `example.com`. However, if the URL is like this:

```
https://www.example.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=!3&From=USD&To=EUR
```

in this URL I submit input value `!3` so I don't want to redirect it. The only thing I want is if the URL contains only `!` value it is redirected to home page else code works normally. How can I do that?

Comment: Please remove unnecessary repetition from your question and, if possible, use standard spelling (sentence starts with upper case, ends with period etc.). It will make it easier for people to figure out what you're after. Then next up, what have you tried? Have you looked at `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`? Or `str_contains()`? For example.

Comment: [ask], the [tour] and [How do I format my posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) would all be sensible to read before you [edit] your question. "I want" isn't even a question.

Comment: @Vasim I've updated my answer to also match URL encoded parameter values (which I assume is the purpose of your first example). Also corrected the mod_rewrite syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If any URL parameter contains exactly `!` only (URL encoded or not) then redirect to the document root. You can do this using mod_rewrite near the top of the root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \=(!|%21)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ / [QSD,R=302,L]
```

**UPDATE:** The regex `\=(!|\%21)(&|$)` matches any URL parameter value where the value is either `!` or `%21` (`!` URL encoded) exactly. Whilst the `=` is not a special regex meta character in this context, it needs to be backslash-escaped to avoid being interpreted as the `=` Apache mod_rewrite prefix-operator. Alternatively, you could match a single character before the literal `=`, eg. `.=`.

The `QSD` flag is necessary to discard the query string from the redirect response.

Note that this rule currently applies to any URL-path. If it should only apply to `/currencyconverter/convert/` (for instance) then be specific in the rule. For example:

```
:
RewriteRule ^currencyconverter/convert/$ / [QSD,R=302,L]
```

NB: The URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash.

---

*Aside:*

But why not block the request with a 403 Forbidden, rather than issue a redirect? ie. use the following `RewriteRule` instead:

```
:
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```